# How to test in react today.getFullYear() + 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to test following line of code in React:

```
const today = new Date()
export const nextYear = today.getFullYear() + 1
```

What I've tried:

```
import { nextYear } from '../nextYear'
import MockDate from 'mockdate'

describe('NextYearHelper', () => {
  describe('nextYear', () => {
    it('returns next year', () => {
      MockDate.set('2030-11-22')
      expect(nextYear).toEqual(2031)
    })
  })
})
```

I can see the mock date in the example calling `new Date()` but test does not pass. I also tried:

```
export const nextYear = () => today.getFullYear() + 1
```

And try to see if `new Date()` returns the mock value, but without success.

1. Why the `new Date()` call is not being mocked in the code and it is in the example?
2. Even for a small computation like this one, should it be a function instead of a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are basically doing is that:

```js
const today = new Date()
const nextYear = today.getFullYear() + 1
var MockDate = require("mockdate")
MockDate.set('2030-11-22')

console.log(nextYear)
```

You cannot mock a date that has already been instanciated.

A solution may be:

```js
export const dynamicNextYear = () => (new Date()).getFullYear() + 1
```

This solution only instanciate a date when the function is called, hence `MockDate` will be able to mock it.

Or you could just use `MockDate` even before you import your file (I'm not enough js expert to tell you about when and how import resolution occurs).

I've made a [runkit](https://runkit.com/buonomo/5fc67d3bc4dac8001a676c0c) to fiddle with.

Comment: so not only I couldn't store the date in a variable, but also I needed to create a function